# C# visual if/else issue

Tags: c#

Hi having abit of a problem with my code it refuses to do my else statement have a global variable set to say attempts = 3

runs the while loop but when i put an invalid pin it basically just doesnt run anything i would appreciate any help possible thanks

```
while (read.Read())
{
    if (read.HasRows)
{
}
    //If the card isnt confiscated then do this:
    if (((Boolean)(read["confiscated"]) == false))
    {
        string cardnum = read["cardNumber"].ToString();
        string pinnum = read["PIN"].ToString();


        //Compare the results in the table against those put in by the customer
        if (string.Equals(cardnum, cardBox.Text) && string.Equals(pinnum, pinNumber.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome customer");
            MessageBox.Show("Card Number " + cardnum + " PIN " + pinnum);
            //if the login details match and everything is correct then bring the next form up
            MessageBox.Show("Details are correct");
            pinNumber.Clear();
            //open the options form
            Form optionForm = new optionForm();
            optionForm.Show();
            //hide this form
            this.Hide();
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            if (attempts == 1)
            {
                sqlCommandATM.Parameters["@cardNum"].Value = cardBox.Text;
                sqlCommandATM.Parameters["@confiscated"].Value = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Your card has been confiscated please contact The bank of Glamorgan to resolve the issue");
                pinNumber.Clear();

            }
```

Comment: Please produce a minimal self-contained example that demonstrates the issue. See http://sscce.org/ for details.

Comment: Is that a correct copy and paste as directly after `if (read.HasRows)` you have an open and close brace making the if statement worthless. You also don't set or increment `attempts` anywhere.

Comment: The basic problem I see here is that you're mixing the DS layer with the UI layer and trying to perform UI operations all within a DataReader's while(reader.Read()) loop.  My guess is that you'll end up with a lot of memory and/or connection leaks doing it this way.

Comment: I really wish universities would teach students to use debuggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
I've tried to understand what you're doing. I assume you're trying to authenticate a person by credit card number and PIN against a database, and you're doing it by getting *all* the entries from a database table and looping over them to find the one that matches the user input. You want to allow the user to do that three times before locking the credit card.

I see more than one issue with that: The task of finding the correct row in the table for the user should be left to the database. This is much quicker and less error prone. So if you'd like to do it right, then you should have an SQL statement like:

```
int attempts = 0;
bool success = false;

while (!success && attempts < 3)
{
    using (SQLCommand exists = new SQLCommand("SELECT ID FROM ... WHERE CCardNo = @cardNo AND PIN = @pin", conn))
    {
        exists.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cardNo", cardNum);
        exists.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PIN", pinnum);

        object idObject = (int)exists.ExecuteScalar();
        if (idObject == null || idObject == DBNull.Value)
        {
            attemps++;
        }
        else
        {
            success = true;
        }

        if (attempts >= 3)
        {
            // Lock out the user
        }
    }
}

if (success)
{
    ...
}
```

If you *really* insist on doing it your way, then please make sure that `attempts` is initialized properly and is incremented on each login attempt - in your current code, you'd increment it on *every row you're validating against*, so you'd lock out every customer who's not within the first three rows you're getting from the database.

**Original reply**

OK, you're reading all data from a DataReader in a `while` loop:

```
while (read.Read())
{
```

Then what do the following three lines do? You wouldn't be here if `read.HasRows` was `false`, because `read.Read()` would have returned `false` already. The following three lines are pointless and can be removed, leaving only what's inside the block.

```
    if (read.HasRows)
    {
    }
```

The usual way would be:

```
if (read.HasRows)
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

More is hard to tell as you're not showing us the complete code - what value does `attempts` have before the `while` loop, for example?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment because I changed my answer... I wrote it as an answer because it would really have been very long and badly formatted as a comment.

Comment: Nice!  Psssst... don't forget the using() statements around IDisposable objects to avoid connection/memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, usually I don't put a `using` around `SqlCommand`s - only around the connection or a `SqlDataReader`. While I know I should be using it on every `IDisposable` (and while I have answered recently that it is recommended to do so), I find myself using `using` only in certain situations while relying totally on the GC in other situations.

Comment: hey guys finished it now sorry about the bad coding ended up with 2 people's codes kinda mixed together and it really threw me off my lecturer just told me to condense it gave me a hint and ended up doing it in 4 lines and it actually works now lol thank you very much for your help tho everyone! :)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar thanks for that as well you was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the syntax errors in your posted code, my first guess is that your `attempts` variable is not set to `1` when control goes inside the `else` statement so, based on your posted code, nothing should happen. Could you show us where this `attempts` variable is declared/changed?

Answer (score 0):

From the code supplied you have not incremented attempts on each attempt the user trys to enter a pin. where teh code is;

```
string pinnum = read["PIN"].ToString();
attempts++;
```

Something like that. Its hard to tell what you have in total as its obviously snipped code.

Answer (score 0):

You said the global `attempts = 3`.

If that's the case, you should check if the failed attempts is >= 3.

```
if (string.Equals(cardnum, cardBox.Text) && string.Equals(pinnum, pinNumber.Text))
{
    // Load account
}
else if (attempts >= 3)
{
    // Confiscate card
}
else
{
    attempts ++;
}
```

Comment: Nah, look at what he's doing. He iterates over all rows of data from a database and checks whether the user has provided valid login information. Apart from the fact that this should be handled by the database, your code would lock the user out after evaluating three rows of data.